# I think im missing linear property in this normed vector space how should i approach?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a normed vector space and $V'$ a subspace, $x\in V-\{0\}$show that

a)If $\exists \eta > 0$, such that $\{y\in V :\space\space ||y||<\eta\}\subset V'$ then $\frac{\eta x}{||x||}\in V'$

never did a problem like this, any hint?

Comment: If $V'$ is a subspace of $V$ and $B(0,\eta) \subset V'$, then $V' = V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the property that $||\lambda v|| = |\lambda| \cdot ||v||$. Apply this to $v := \frac{\eta x}{2||x||}$ to deduce that $v \in V'$. Then use the fact that $V'$ is a subspace to deduce that $2v \in V'$.

Comment: I can see this is equal to $\eta$ but this only convinced me this is out the ball in $V'$